# php ternary operator - doesn't short circuit with multiple if's

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am getting a strange result from using a ternary oparator to change the value of an integer to a grouped string.

In javascript this code would work as the ternary operator would short circuit when it get's the first true.

My code for some reason is giving a return value of `'B'` most of the time, but can print `'A'`. Is there any way to return when the first match occurs, or do I have to change the structure if to `if/else` conditions.

```
function graderator($grade) {
  return (
    $grade < 65 ? 'F' :
    $grade < 70 ? 'D' :
    $grade < 80 ? 'C' :
    $grade < 90 ? 'B' : 'A'
  );
};

var_dump(graderator(58)); // => 'B' should be 'F'
var_dump(graderator(68)); // => 'B' should be 'D'
var_dump(graderator(78)); // => 'B' should be 'C'
var_dump(graderator(88)); // => 'B' should be 'B'
var_dump(graderator(98)); // => 'A' should be 'A'
```

Cheers

Comment: you should be aware that `the ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right`

Comment: RTFM: [This is exactly why the PHP docs has warning notes about stacking ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: More precisely this is a well known 'issue' of PHP's version of ternary operators. Other languages ... don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis

```
function graderator($grade) {
  return (
    $grade < 65 ? 'F' :
    ($grade < 70 ? 'D' :
    ($grade < 80 ? 'C' :
    ($grade < 90 ? 'B' : 'A')))
  );
};
```